# Query With array in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch contents of two separate category and insert them in two different boxes. 
I have written the query like this:

```
$query = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREFIX."_links WHERE cat = %d LIMIT %d" , 4, 3));
```

But can we write 2 or more query in one query? like :"select * from blah where cat = (3, 4, 5)"

EDIT:
 [image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update 2

To load your data in a specific div, you can store the result in an array and later echo it where you want like this:

```
$result = mysql_query(...........);

$i = 0;
$data = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $data[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- For div 1 -->
<div>
  <?php echo $data[0]['fieldName']?>
</div>

<!-- For div 2 -->
<div>
  <?php echo $data[1]['fieldName']?>
</div>

<!-- For div 3 -->
<div>
  <?php echo $data[2]['fieldName']?>
</div>
```

---

### Update

```
You can do something like this:

    $result = mysql_query(...........);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      echo '<div>' . $row['fieldName'] . '</div>'
    }
```

This way each record will appear in different div.

---

> But can we write 2 or more query in
>   one query? like :"select * from blah
>   where cat = (3, 4, 5)"

You can do so with `IN` operator:

```
select * from blah where cat IN (3, 4, 5)
```

> The IN operator allows you to specify
>   multiple values in a WHERE clause.

**More Information:**

- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: After query, how can I separate each result to separate div ? For example, category 1 contents in <div>content of category1</div> , <div>content of category2</div>

Comment: This: <?php echo $data[0]['fieldName']?> will show only one row. I want to make only one query and then separate them. All contents of one category in separate box. I think I have to separate the query :((

Comment: @phpExe: You can use `print_r($data)` to see the data and use it however you like :)

Answer (score 2):

just use the IN statement of SQL

```
SELECT * FROM _links WHERE cat IN (3,4,5)
```